# Report Builder expression return string when SUM evaluates to false

Tags: vb.net, report, ssrs-2012

I'm using Microsoft Report Builder to create a report that prints 900 school report cards.  The only type of expression I can get working that returns the grade (from SQL query) is a SUM.  But when SQL has a 0 I want to return/print a string that says "N/A" I understand SUM is looking for an integer, so I can only get it to return "0" or I can use "nothing" to get blank.  Is there another expression, or can I convert the integer somehow?  I tried using just IIF, but kept getting errors on too many conditions.  Here is my expression...

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!StudentPeriod.value = "2" And Fields!SkillFour.value > "0", Fields!SkillFour.value, nothing), "UserName")
```

Comment: How about using [Custom Function](http://www.venkateswarlu.co.in/MSBI/ssrs/Custom_Functions.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways. You can warp around your expression another condition:

```
=IIF(SUM(IIF(Fields!StudentPeriod.value = "2" And Fields!SkillFour.value > "0", Fields!SkillFour.value, Nothing), "UserName") = Nothing, "N/A", SUM(IIF(Fields!StudentPeriod.value = "2" And Fields!SkillFour.value > "0", Fields!SkillFour.value, nothing), "UserName"))
```

Or you can go under the textbox properties **Number > Currency** and check the option **Show value as -/(None)**.

Also, you should not use such an condition:

```
Fields!SkillFour.Value > "0"
```

This indicats that your value `"0"` is a string and you want to use a mathematical symbol `>` on a string. You should convert it to an integer or double with

```
CInt(Fields!SkillFour.Value) > 0
```

Comment: Thank you SO much.  Putting my expression in another condition worked great.